# Setiment Analysis - Dataset .map() is not mapping string to int

Tags: python, twitter, data-analysis

I’m completely new to python and data analysis.
I’m trying to analyze twitter data and here is a screenshot of my Dataset.

I'm trying to map the sentiment which is (POS, NUT, NEG) to numbers like 0, 1, 2

so i write this code and it doesn’t work, does anyone knows why?

```
dfMain['Sentiment'] = dfMain['Sentiment'].map({'POS': 0, 'NUT': 1, 'NEG': 2}) # 0 => Postivie sentiment; 1 => Neutral sentiment; 1 => Negative sentiment
```

Note: dfMain contains dataset.

Answer (score 0):

so the map function takes a list and a function and applies that function to every item in that list and then returns a map object. This is great and you can just google it to get more info, but what you want is apply a function to a pandas dataframe.
Pandas uses the .apply method to apply a function to every item in that dataframe. To use it the way you want to you could do the following:

```
d = {"POS": 0, "NUT": 1, "NEG": 2}

def sentiment_to_numbers(x):
    return d[x]

dfMain["Sentiment"] = dfMain["Sentiment"].apply(sentiment_to_numbers)
```

So what you do is you create a dictionary d that maps your strings to integers and then create a function that takes an input and returns the dictionarys value for that input. Then you apply that function to the dataframe.

If you dont want to create that function you could use lambdas, but maybe thats left for another time.